# RavenDb 2.5 - TransformWith() not working after Where()

Tags: indexing, ravendb

I am trying to perform a query where I need to filter on a property before I perform a transform, but the return type of Where() is IQueryable which apparently does not have a TransformWith extension method. What gives? The documentation examples show exactly this being performed.

```
session.Query<LocalizedService, LocalizedServicesIndex>()
            .Where(s => s.Culture == Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture)
            .TransformWith<LocalizedServiceTransformer, LocalizedService>()
            .ToList();
```

The indexed documents are of Type Service, and LocalizedService is a projection Type that is stored in the index.

Anyone run into this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .Where(...) in your case is using the standard where in "System.Linq" namespace but in order to use .TransformWith<>() you need to use the .Where(...) extension in "Raven.Client.Linq" namespace.

Make sure you have:

```
using Raven.Client.Linq;
```

in your code.

Comment: you were absolutely correct. Feeling a bit foolish now. ;)